# how to delete all fields which their key starts with something in mongo php

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, key, database

I guess it will be a regular expression and an unset command
but I can't figure out the syntax for the keys.

All of the examples are for the values, and not for the key

```
$regexObj = new MongoRegex("/^startwith/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually do regex operations on keys in MongoDB.

If this is an operation you need to perform frequently you may wish to look into using key value sotres instead, i.e.:

```
[
    {k: 'name', v: 'Sammaye'}
]
```

Without the key value store the best way currently is to actually pick out each document, delete the fields and then resave it again.